# The contract name could not be found using - Web Services Contract First sample

Tags: wcf

I am new to WCF, I have created a simple WCF application (Contract First sample ). But getting an error for service file. Any help would be great.

1. Created a project using VS 2010 - Select WCF Application.
2. Delete Iservice1 and Service1.svc, then update web.config accordingly
3. Added schemas in XSD folder
4. Create .WSDL by right click on CustomerMesages.xsd, select WSCF.blue - Select 'Create WSDL Interface Description'
5. Once the .WSDL is created, create the Web Service code by right click .wsdl file, select WSCF.blue - Select 'Generate Web Service Code'
6. Add .SVC file to the project
7. Delete the Interface file that is created.
8. Update the .svc and web.config
9. Error:  The contract name 'XXXXXXService.XXXXXService' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service 'XXXXXXService.

   ```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <xs:schema id="Cust_Input"
           targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/ServiceDemo:data"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns="http://tempuri.org/ServiceDemo:data"
           xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/ServiceDemo:data"
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

         <xs:complexType name="GetCustDetailsInput">
           <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="KEY" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
               <xs:complexType>
                 <xs:sequence>
                   <xs:element name="CUST_ID"  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" >
                     <xs:simpleType>
                       <xs:restriction base="xs:double">
                         <xs:minInclusive value="0"></xs:minInclusive>
                         <xs:maxInclusive value="99999999999"></xs:maxInclusive>
                       </xs:restriction>
                     </xs:simpleType>
                   </xs:element>            
                 </xs:sequence>
               </xs:complexType>
             </xs:element>
           </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
         <xs:element name="GetCustDetailsInput" type="GetCustDetailsInput"></xs:element>
       </xs:schema>

         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <xs:schema id="Cust_Output"
           targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/ServiceDemo:data"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns="http://tempuri.org/ServiceDemo:data"
           xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/ServiceDemo:data"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

         <xs:complexType name="GetCustDetailsOutput">
           <xs:sequence>     
             <xs:element name="KEY" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
               <xs:complexType>
                 <xs:sequence>
                   <xs:element name="L_Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                   <xs:element name="F_Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                   <xs:element name="ERR_MSG" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                 </xs:sequence>
               </xs:complexType>
             </xs:element>
           </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
         <xs:element type="GetCustDetailsOutput" name="GetCustDetailsOutput"></xs:element>
       </xs:schema>

         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <xs:schema id="CustomerMessages"
           targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/ServiceDemo:messages"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns="http://tempuri.org/ServiceDemo:messages"
           xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/ServiceDemo:messages"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:input="http://tempuri.org/ServiceDemo:data"
           xmlns:output="http://tempuri.org/ServiceDemo:data">

         <xs:import id="GetCustDetailsInputXsd" schemaLocation="Cust_Input.xsd" namespace="http://tempuri.org/ServiceDemo:data"/>
         <xs:import id="GetCustDetailsOutputXsd" schemaLocation="Cust_Output.xsd" namespace="http://tempuri.org/ServiceDemo:data"/>

         <xs:complexType name="GetCustDetailsRequest">
           <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="GetCustDetailsInput" type="input:GetCustDetailsInput"/>
           </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
         <xs:element name="GetCustDetailsRequest"  type="mstns:GetCustDetailsRequest"></xs:element>
         <xs:complexType name="GetCustDetailsResponse">
           <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="GetCustDetailsOutput" type="output:GetCustDetailsOutput"/>
           </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
         <xs:element name="GetCustDetailsResponse" type="mstns:GetCustDetailsResponse"/>
       </xs:schema>
   ```

Adding web.config service model section

```
    <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="CustomerService.CustomerTestServiceBehavior"
    name="CustomerService.CustomerTestService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="CustomerService.CustomerService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CustomerService.CustomerTestServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

CustomerService.CustomerService Code:
namespace CustomerService
{

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/demos:ServiceDemo", ConfigurationName="ICustomerService")]
public interface ICustomerService
{

    // CODEGEN: Generating message contract since the wrapper namespace (http://tempuri.org/ServiceDemo:messages) of message GetCustDetailsRequest does not match the default value (http://tempuri.org/demos:ServiceDemo)
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/demos:ServiceDemo/ICustomerService/GetCustDetails", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/demos:ServiceDemo/ICustomerService/GetCustDetailsResponse")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
    GetCustDetailsResponse GetCustDetails(GetCustDetailsRequest request);
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34234")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/ServiceDemo:data")]
public partial class GetCustDetailsInput : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private GetCustDetailsInputKEY kEYField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public GetCustDetailsInputKEY KEY
    {
        get
        {
            return this.kEYField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.kEYField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("KEY");
        }
    }       

}

......
.....

public class ObjectCollection : System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<object>
{
}

[System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehaviorAttribute(InstanceContextMode=System.ServiceModel.InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode=System.ServiceModel.ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
public partial class CustomerService : ICustomerService
{

    public virtual GetCustDetailsResponse GetCustDetails(GetCustDetailsRequest request)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The web.config would be more useful than the WSDL.

Comment: Added the web.config

Comment: What is the name of the contract, with the namespace?  Can you post the contract and service implementation code?  `CustomerService.CustomerService` is what is being reported as the error, so it's a good bet your fully-qualified contract name is not right.

Comment: CustomerTestService.svc.cs code:

namespace CustomerService
{

    public class CustomerTestService : CustomerService
    {
        public void DoWork()
        {
        }
    }
}

Comment: The error I am getting is - 

The contract name 'CustomerService.CustomerService' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service 'CustomerTestService'.

Comment: Is your interface `CustomerService.CustomerService`?  Or is it something else?

Comment: As Tom says, you need to show us your service implementation code, which is the C# code which implements your service.

Comment: Yes. Interface is CustomerService.CustomerService. Step 5.Once the .WSDL is created, create the Web Service code by right click .wsdl file, select WSCF.blue - Select 'Generate Web Service Code'. Posted the part of the code.